# ¿Cómo contar la cantidad de productos de una cabecera y detalle si no es mayor a 10?

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

Tengo un script que consulta datos de algunas tablas los datos que quiero recuperar son el codigo del presupuesto de ventas y la cantidad de productos detallado que tuvo movimiento solo si la cantidad es menor a 10 ademas tambien lo estoy filtrando por codigo de rubro y fecha, he tratado de hacerlo con **HAVING sum(det.CANTIDAD)<10** pero de igual manera filtra los datos si las cantidades suman mayor a diez

```js
SELECT all SUM(distinct det.CANTIDAD) as SUMA, det.CANTIDAD, p.CODIGOBARRA, v.CODPRESUPUESTOORIGINAL, v.FECHAVENTA
FROM PRESUPUESTOVENTASDETALLE det, VENTAS v, productos p, PRESUPUESTOVENTAS pv, RUBRO r, CLIENTES c

where p.CODRUBRO in (190, 205) and v.FECHAVENTA between '20221101 00:00:00'
and '20221231 23:59:59'
and v.ESTADO < > 1
and p.CODPRODUCTO = det.CODPRODUCTO and det.CODPRESUPUESTO = v.CODPRESUPUESTOORIGINAL
AND pv.CODPRESUPUESTO = det.CODPRESUPUESTO and v.CODPRESUPUESTOORIGINAL = pv.CODPRESUPUESTO
and p.CODPRODUCTO = det.CODPRODUCTO and r.CODRUBRO = p.CODRUBRO and c.codcliente = pv.codcliente

GROUP BY v.CODPRESUPUESTOORIGINAL, p.CODIGOBARRA, det.CODPRESUPUESTO, v.FECHAVENTA, det.CANTIDAD

having sum(distinct det.CANTIDAD) < 10

ORDER BY det.CODPRESUPUESTO
```

¿Cómo puedo recuperar el detalle con los productos y la cantidad si la suma no supera 10, el resultado de mi consulta se ve de esta forma ahora

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como primera medida tendrias que quitar el det.CANTIDAD del group by.

por las dudas te lo dejo con las composiciones internas como inner join, la clausa all del select la omiti pues es la default.

```sql
SELECT  v.CODPRESUPUESTOORIGINAL, p.CODIGOBARRA, det.CODPRESUPUESTO, v.FECHAVENTASUM, sum(distinct det.CANTIDAD) as SUMA
FROM PRESUPUESTOVENTASDETALLE det
inner join productos p
    on p.CODPRODUCTO = det.CODPRODUCTO
inner join VENTAS v
    on det.CODPRESUPUESTO = v.CODPRESUPUESTOORIGINAL
inner join PRESUPUESTOVENTAS pv
    on pv.CODPRESUPUESTO = det.CODPRESUPUESTO
inner join  RUBRO r
    on r.CODRUBRO = p.CODRUBRO
inner join CLIENTES c
    on c.codcliente = pv.codcliente

where p.CODRUBRO in (190, 205) 
    and convert(char(8),v.FECHAVENTA,112) between '20221101' and '20221231'
    and v.ESTADO < > 1
GROUP BY v.CODPRESUPUESTOORIGINAL, p.CODIGOBARRA, det.CODPRESUPUESTO, v.FECHAVENTA
having sum(distinct det.CANTIDAD) < 10
ORDER BY det.CODPRESUPUESTO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si queres recuperar las ventas donde la suma de las cantidades es menor o igual a 10, podes cambiar la cláusula de 'having' por:

```
SUM(DISTINCT det.CANTIDAD) < 10
```

Comment: ya lo probe de esta forma **having sum(distinct det.CANTIDAD) < 10**  pero aun sigue filtrando todos aun si es mayor a 10